# Scanning for groups of the same value in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array where 0 denotes empty space and 1 denotes that a location is filled. I am trying to find a quick method of scanning the numpy array for where there are multiple values of zero adjacent to each other and return the location of the central zero.

For Example if I had the following array

```
[0 1 0 1]
[0 0 0 1]
[0 1 0 1]
[1 1 1 1]
```

I want to return the locations for which there is an adjacent zero on either side of a central zero

e.g

```
[1,1]
```

as this is the central of 3 zeros, i.e there is a zero either side of the zero at this location

Im aware that this can be calculated using if statements, but wondered if there was a more pythonic way of doing this.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: How is `[0, 1]` the correct output for your example input ? "as this is the central of 3 zeros" isn't helping.

Comment: Apologies for the typo, it should have been 1,1 ive updated the question accordingly

Comment: If there are 4 consecutive `0`s, which one should be considered as the central `0`?

Comment: thats a good point and something im still considering at the moment, in reality Ill be looking for 30-50 zeros in a row, but you make a good point regarding the 'central' location for an even number of zeros

Comment: what about, if we consider the column direction, both [1,0] and [1,2] have central zeros in vertical directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired output here for arbitrary inputs is not exhaustively specified in the question, but here is a possible approach that might be useful for this kind of problem, and adapted to the details of the desired output. It uses `np.cumsum`, `np.bincount`, `np.where`, and `np.median` to find the middle index for groups of consecutive zeros along rows of a 2D array:

```python
import numpy as np

def find_groups(x, min_size=3, value=0):
  # Compute a sequential label for groups in each row. 
  xc = (x != value).cumsum(1)

  # Count the number of occurances per group in each row.
  counts = np.apply_along_axis(
      lambda x: np.bincount(x, minlength=1 + xc.max()),
      axis=1, arr=xc)

  # Filter by minimum number of occurances.
  i, j = np.where(counts >= min_size)

  # Compute the median index of each group.
  return [
    (ii, int(np.ceil(np.median(np.where(xc[ii] == jj)[0]))))
    for ii, jj in zip(i, j)
  ]

x = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 1, 0, 1],
              [1, 1, 1, 1]])

print(find_groups(x))
# [(1, 1)]
```

It should work properly even for multiple rows with groups of varying sizes, and even multiple groups per row:

```python
x2 = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
               [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

print(find_groups(x2))
# [(1, 1), (1, 5), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
```